# Oracle PL SQL Function return type size VARCHAR2(32767) incorrectly?

Tags: oracle, plsql, amazon-rds

struggling with a PL/SQL Function here (new to me) - and what makes this weird is it appears to work on Oracle XE (local) and Oracle 12c - but when applied to AWS RDS Oracle instances it does not work.

I have a function which is returning a query column value from another table, and I am trying to add a function derived column to a new table.

The database is currently empty as it is being designed.

**TableA**

```
CompanyID      Integer
VALUE          VARCHAR2(128)
```

**Function - This works executing in SQL Developer**

```
create or replace FUNCTION MyFunction
    (
        CompanyID IN INT 
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2
    DETERMINISTIC
    IS result VARCHAR2(128);
    BEGIN
        SELECT "VALUE" INTO result
        FROM "TableA"
        WHERE "CompanyID" = CompanyID;
        RETURN result;
    END MyFunction;
```

**Next - Alter TableB to add column referencing MyFunction**

```
ALTER TABLE "TableB" ADD "TableAValue" VARCHAR2(128) AS (MyFunction("CompanyID"))
```

**Observe error**

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column "TableAValue" (actual: 32767, maximum: 128)
12899. 00000 -  "value too large for column %s (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"
```

It's working OK in Oracle XE as mentioned - but when trying to create my database on AWS RDS Oracle, it's like it cannot determine that the size of column TableA.VALUE is only 128 in size, and treating it as maximum (for extended string size settings).

Am I missing something in the function that can force the DB Engine to see that it is appropriately sized? I have tried casting the SELECT "VALUE" to VARCHAR2(128) as well but that made no difference.

A bit confused, appreciate any insight!

Comment: 1) Stop using quoted identifiers as it is just confusing to have `"Id"` and `ID` referring to two different variables. 2) Your function is not `DETERMINISTIC` and should not be defined as such just to bypass the error you get when you try to use `ALTER TABLE ... ADD ...` with a non-deterministic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a function and don't declare non-deterministic functions as `DETERMINISTIC` when they are not.

Instead, create a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW tableb_view AS
SELECT b.*,
       a.value AS tableavalue
FROM   tableb b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tablea a
       ON b.id = a.id
```

---

If you really want to use your function (**DON'T**) then you can specify the size using `CAST`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD TableAValue VARCHAR2(128) AS (
  CAST( MyFunction(CompanyID) AS VARCHAR2(128) )
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick input - I will look into the View option to see if it can work with the application being developed. Thanks once again!

Comment: @watdo I do not know what your motivation is for using a function but every time you select `tableavalue` from `tableb` then, for each row, that will involve a call to the function which will context switch to PL/SQL and then context switch back to SQL to perform the query inside the function and may involve addition I/O; this is likely to hugely impact performance. Using a view and selecting from the view is not going to have the overheads of context-switching (and may be able to optimise the I/O).